# First Isomorphism Theorem - hole in the proof from my book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I have a book that contains a proof for their so-called "First Isomorphism Theorem", which esentially states that if $f$ is a surjective group morphism $f:G\to G'$ and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G'/f(H)$.

Their proof goes like this:

They consider $\pi: G' \to G'/f(H)$ to be the canonical map, $\pi(x) = xf(H)$, which is surjective. Then they take $f':G\to G'/f(H), \ f'=\pi \circ f$. Since $f$ and $\pi$ are surjective, $f'$ is also surjective. Thus, by a previously proven theorem in the book (called the 'Fundamental Isomorphism Theorem'), we have that $G/\ker f'$ is isomorphic to $G'/f(H)$.

Now they go on to prove that $\ker f' = H$ in order to finalize the proof.

The following sequence of equivalences holds:

$x \in \ker f' \Leftrightarrow \pi(f(x)) = 1 \Leftrightarrow f(x) \in \ker \pi = f(H)$. (the $1$ here is the unity for $G'/f(H)$, so $f(H)$).

So now we have $f(\ker f') =f(H)$ and now comes the part where I get stuck. They now call on a previously proven theorem (called the Correspondence Theorem for Normal Subgroups), which states that if we have a surjective group morphism $f:G\to G'$, then the map $H\to f(H)$ from the set of normal subgroups of $G$ that contain $\ker f$ to the set of normal subgroups of $G'$ is bijective), but this does not look correct as we have no knowledge of whether $H$ actually contains $\ker f$ ($\ker f'$ does).

I also thought of $\pi$'ing the equality and instead using $f'(\ker f') = f'(H)$, but we don't know that $\ker f'$ belongs to $H$ either).

**EDIT: ** Source of the faulty theorem: The Romanian book "Bazele Algebrei, vol. I" (English would probably be "Fundamentals of Algebra) by C. Năstăsecu, C. Niță and C. Vraciu, Bucharest, 1986. The page is 54 and the theorem I mentioned is Proposition 3.19.

Comment: You'll have to assume $H$ contains $ker(f)$ for this to be true. For example consider $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and take $H$ to be the trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. This leads me to ask what you mean by "essentially states".

Comment: That is an awesome example. Thank you. Well, I wrote 'esentially states' because I thought I did not copy the exact wording. Now that I look at the book, it also looks like the theorem states another conclusion, namely that f(H) is normal in G', but I did not write it as I thought it is well-known to people specialized in abstract algebra.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So the authors must have forgotten to add this condition to the statement. I will turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: Please do, it really helped. I really hope the theorem is not used in its wrong form in what comes next in the book...

Comment: My guess is probably they don't, since taking this statement at face value would lead to drastically incorrect conclusions. But good catch on your part nonetheless.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @halrankard2 I really tried to follow the book's group section line by line, including the proofs, which is probably why I caught it ^^. I am actually transcribing everything on a notebook in order to have them better stay in my mind.

Comment: @Shaun The book is the Romanian book  "Bazele Algebrei" (English would probably be "Fundamentals of Algebra) by C. Năstăsecu, C. Niță and C. Vraciu. The page is 54 and the theorem I mentioned if Proposition 3.19. I'm also adding this to the main post as halrankard2 suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the authors forgot to add the assumption that $H$ contains $\ker (f)$ to the statement of the result.

One can find many cases where the assertion fails without an assumption like this. For example let $G$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ and let $H$ be the trivial subgroup. For any $n\geq 1$, we have a surjective homomorphism $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $G'=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and $f(H)$ is still the trivial subgroup. In particular, $G/H$ and $G'/f(H)$ are not isomorphic.

Taking $n=1$ in the previous situation shows how drastic the error is. Indeed, given *any* nontrivial group $G$, consider the surjective homomorphism $f:G\to G'$, where $G'$ is trivial group. If $H$ is the trivial subgroup of $G$, then $G/H=G$ and $G'/f(H)$ is trivial.

More generally if this formulation of the First Isomorphism Theorem were true then it would imply that anytime there is a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$, then $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, which is absurd.

I might also suggest you edit your question to add the name of the book and page number. This could help future users who run into the same problem.

Comment: I have to ask what you exactly mean by $G/H = G$ in the 3rd paragraph. I see $G/H$ is very similar to G, but it actually contains $G$'s elements as one-element sets. Maybe this should've been an isomorphism relationship instead of an equality? Also, the 4th paragraph directly follows from the 3rd considerign $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G$ if $H$ is trivial, right?

Comment: Yes, technically I do only mean that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G$. This is a common abuse of notation, especially in such cases where the isomorphism is so canonical. Your analysis of the fourth paragraph is correct.